# Add a link next to the heading of a block

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drupal, block

[drupal block heading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RmYZ.png)

I'm trying to add a link next to the heading of this block by clicking it will goes to more news.

I've used css pseudo ::after to add text and a logo. But I couldn't add a link to the text. Can i add any link with css or should i use JS for this ?

Comment: not a task for a pseudo-element. Add a real link by using the anchor tag. Also not a task for JS or jquery. It should be either hardcoded through HTML or PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply make a block template do to this. Example in D9/twig

```
{% if label %}
  <h2{{ title_attributes.addClass('block--title') }}>{{ label }}</h2> <a href="#">More news </a>
{% endif %}
```

If you need, turn on template suggestions do help you find the right block suggestion.

If you are still using D7, again you can just amend the template for the block:

```
 <div<?php print $attributes; ?>>
      <div class="block-inner clearfix">
        <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
        <?php if ($block->subject): ?>
          <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject; ?></h2> 
<a href="#">More news </a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
        
        <div<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
          <?php print $content ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The site is still on Drupal 7.9x Not sure this will work on there. So there is no way i can do this with CSS right ? Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: There's no need to do it with CSS if you can use a template.  I've added a D7 example. In your themes/themename/templates/block folder, add the block template with the correct suggestion for your block.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The heading which i'm looking to modify is actually a slideshow showing news. I found that the relevant block template is coming from another theme and if i change it does it effects for other blocks as well ? If so how can i make a new block template and call it ?

Comment: You can make it more specific based on the context.  Should should be able to do it via view display ID if you require.